# Array to string conversion in Doctrine for simple_array field

Tags: php, arrays, doctrine-orm

I would like to import data from a JSON file to a database table. I'm using Doctrine with the pdo_sqlite driver and the following entity is configured :

```
/**
 * @Entity @Table(name="mytable")
 **/
class MyClass
{
    /** @Id @Column(type="integer") @GeneratedValue *
     * @Column(type="integer")
     */
    var $id;

    /** @Column(type="string") **/
    var $name;


    /** @Column(type="simple_array") **/
    var $parameters;

    function __construct($name, $parameters)
    {
        $this->name = $name;
        $this->parameters = $parameters;
    }

    // getters and setters here
}
```

I have created a simple import method :

```
function importFromJson($tableName, $fileName)
    {
        if (file_exists($fileName)) {
            $data = json_decode(file_get_contents($fileName));
            if (is_array($data)) {
                $connection = getEm()->getConnection();
                foreach($data as $tuple) {
                    if (is_object($tuple)) {
                        $connection->insert($tableName, (array)$tuple);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

My import.json file contains the following text :

```
[
  {
    "name": "A name",
    "parameters": ["a","b","c"]
  }
]
```

When I call my import method :

```
importFromJson("mytable", "import.json");
```

I get the following error :

> An exception occurred while executing 'INSERT INTO mytable
>   (name, parameters) VALUES (?, ?)'
>   with params ["A name", ["a","b","c"]]:
>
> Array to string conversion 
>   C:\myproject\vendor\doctrine\dbal\lib\Doctrine\DBAL\DBALException.php:119
>   C:\myproject\vendor\doctrine\dbal\lib\Doctrine\DBAL\Connection.php:996
>   C:\myproject\vendor\doctrine\dbal\lib\Doctrine\DBAL\Connection.php:696
>   C:\myproject\lib\import.php:39

Isn't the exact purpose of the simple_array type to convert arrays to strings that can be stored in the database ?

Comment: If you need to store array data, try `json_encode($array)` function. This will convert your array to string. Then while retrieving data, call `json_decode($string)` function.

Comment: Isn't that supposed to be [automatically handled when I configure a simple_array field](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/basic-mapping.html#doctrine-mapping-types) ?

Comment: I see. What happens if you try setting simple empty array?

Comment: The same error appears, same thing if I use the "array" type instead of "simple_array". Even more strange : if I use the type "object" and I replace the JSON file by the following content :
[
  {
    "name": "A name",
    "parameters": {}
  }
]

I get the error "Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string"

Comment: For clarity, which is the version of Doctrine you are using?

Comment: Here are the versions that I use, I don't know which ones are relevant for this issue : 
doctrine/annotations         v1.2.6
doctrine/cache               v1.4.1
doctrine/collections         v1.3.0
doctrine/common              v2.5.0
doctrine/dbal                v2.5.1
doctrine/inflector           v1.0.1 
doctrine/instantiator        1.0.5
doctrine/lexer               v1.0.1
doctrine/orm                 v2.4.7

Comment: Just a note: As for `simple_array`, in the docs you reference there is note *Only use this type if you are sure that your values cannot contain a ”,”.* Thus you can only use `array` or `json_array` type.

Comment: Right, however even if I use ```array``` or ```json_array``` an provide an empty array I get the error

Comment: @BrunoPérel Did you ever figure this out?  I am having similar issues. It works in dev but not prod

Answer (score -1):

I don't know why you have to store params like an array in a DB but an easy way to do store it first you should convert the `parameters` into a valid string, otherwise it can't be properly stored.

```
foreach($data as $tuple) {
    if (is_object($tuple)) {
        $touple = implode(",", (array)$touple);
        $connection->insert($tableName, (array)$tuple);
    }
}
```

another option could be to convert it as a json string

```
foreach($data as $tuple) {
    if (is_object($tuple)) {
        $touple = json_encode($touple);
        $connection->insert($tableName, (array)$tuple);
    }
}
```

And to be able to use the data when using `select` you should convert the data back to array using either `explode()` or `json_encode` again.Hope this woks! :)

Comment: Of course I can do it manually, but I thought that the whole purpose of configuring a [simple_array field](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/basic-mapping.html#doctrine-mapping-types) was that it would handle these conversions automatically